# Does verifying the signature of an RS256 JWT really take half a second?

Tags: javascript, performance, jwt, signature, verify

I am trying to verify a JWT signature in Javascript using a public key. I have tried the 'jose' and 'jsrsasign' libraries with similar results: the verification is painfully slow (400-500ms).

After googling, from what I can understand the actual verification of the signature should be sub-millisecond. Am I doing something wrong or have i misunderstood what people are saying?

This is what the current code looks like using 'jsrsasign':

```js
import rs from 'jsrsasign';

// [...]

const timeBeforeTokenVerify = Date.now();
const keyObject = rs.KEYUTIL.getKey(jwks.keys[0]);
const isValid = rs.jws.JWS.verifyJWT(clientToken, keyObject, { alg: ['RS256'] });
if (!isValid) {
  throw new Error('Token is not valid');
}
console.log(Date.now() - timeBeforeTokenVerify) // prints 400 to 500
```

Comment: That's certainly unusual. Does it happen on the first call only or also on subsequent calls?

Comment: @Bergi Also on subsequent calls.

Comment: You might want to report a bug in their issue tracker then.